# bottle templating

Tags: python, bottle

I recently got into bottlepy and this is pretty much my first experience with a template engine.(Prior I would simply make what I needed in traditional PHP)

My question is this, let's say I have a base layout(A simple HTML/CSS layout), and, for example; a login box on the side. How do I keep the login box dynamically up to date without having to pass values to it on every route?

Take this for example:

```
from bottle import route,template

@route('/')
def main():

    return template("content.tpl") #rebase from layout.tpl
```

layout.tpl:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{title}}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        %include
        <div id='sidebar'><!-- login box --></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I guess my main question here is how do I make sure the login box runs without having to insert the variables for it at every single page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with bottle, but for other templating engine this sort of thing is done via inheritance.

For example,

Imagine you have a base template called `content.tpl` that looks something like what you have for your `layout.tpl`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{title}}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='sidebar'>%% section "sidebar" %%</div>
        <div id='content'>%% section "content" %%</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that this is pseudocode - the stuff marked out by `%% ... %%` is made up & doesn't correspond to any particular templating engine (AFAIK).

For your login page, you would have another template file called `login.tpl`:

```
%% extends "content.tpl" %%

%% start section "sidebar" %%
    <!-- whatever you put here will be rendered -->
    <!-- in the "sidebar" section of the parent -->
%% end section "sidebar" %%

%% start section "content" %%
    <!-- whatever you put here will be rendered -->
    <!-- in the "content" section of the parent -->

    <form> ... </form>
%% end section "content" %%
```

Then, in your route for your login page, you would do something like this:

```
`return template("login.tpl")`
```

This will cause the template engine to load `login.tpl`, fill in the values it has, and then load the `content.tpl` and stick the stuff it put together for the "sidebar" and "content" sections into the appropriate spots.

There is another mechanism for composing a page from multiple templates: including a file. This would be similar to the example above, exception your login page would look something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{title}}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='sidebar'>%% include "sidebar.tpl" %%</div>
        <div id='content'>%% include "content.tpl" %%</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The main differences between them are:

1. when you're inheriting, you don't have repeat everything on every page - stuff that's constant for all pages can be inherited from the parent layout.
2. when you're inheriting, you can also include stuff from multiple templates into one. For example, imagine that you have templates that inherit like this "main.tpl" -> "template1.tpl" -> "template2.tpl". It is possible in some template engines to set it up so that each template can add to a section, so that the contents can be a composite of the whole family of templates.

Of course, it is possible to use a mix of these techniques as well.

Comment: My point is, say you're calling a template like this: template("some_page.tpl",title="something"), even when inheriting there is no way to pass values to the login box. (eg cookie information). That is unless I'm missing something here

Comment: In templating engines I've used (mostly PHP: Smarty, Blade, and a couple of others briefly), passing a value to the`template()` method makes it available in all templates: inherited or included.

Comment: Yeah, but assuming I'm making for example this page: @route('/testpage') def testpage(): return template('testpage.tpl',title="test"), how do I also pass values to the login box without repeating it every time when testpage.tpl relies on a base layout?

Comment: Ahh, I see the problem. In Laravel (PHP Framework) I've done this using a "view composer" which is code that is executed every time a view is rendered - I use this to insert some values that are necessary for every page. I don't know if bottle has equivalent functionality.

Answer (score 4):

To make a variable available in all templates, put something like this before your routes:

```
from bottle import BaseTemplate

BaseTemplate.defaults['symbol_name'] = value
```

I use this to add helper functions for my templates.

A more correct solution may involve writing a plugin, which is not terribly difficult and is covered in the Bottle documentation.

[Source](http://nongraphical.com/2013/05/bottlepy-use-get_url-from-any-template-file/)